# group by with subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to know if it is possible to use a subquery in group by? Using sqlite as an example, with these tables:

```
create table t (foo int, bar int);
insert into t values (100, 100);
insert into t values (200, 200);
```

Then running this query:

```
select max(bar), foo from t group by (select 1);
```

returns

```
max(bar)    foo       
----------  ----------
200         200
```

I am not sure what that means? Seems like whatever subquery I put in the group by, sqlite will still return the same "answer."

Comment: And what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2):

When you're using GROUP BY, the database computes the expression that you give in the GROUP BY for each row, and creates a group for each distinct result of this expression.

In your query, `(select 1)` results in the same value for all rows, so all rows end up in the same group.

It does not make sense to use an expression that does not depend somehow on the table row.
Using a subquery might be somewhat useful if you're using a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to look up some other value:

```
> create table users(id, name);
> insert into users values (1, 'Tom'), (2, 'Dick'), (3, 'Harry');
> create table admins(userid);
> insert into admins values (1), (3);
> select group_concat(name)
  from user
  group by (select 1
            from admins
            where userid = user.id);
Dick
Tom,Harry
```

However, the result of such a query does not identify which group is which unless you add the same subquery to the SELECT clause.